# How to use Dispatch for multiple Luis model with different cultures

Tags: botframework, azure-language-understanding

I am working on a bot which will have multiple languages(English, French and Spanish). So that I have created multiple Luis models with different cultures i.e en-us, fr-fr and es-es. Now how to add Dispatch for this? I am able to create dispatch for the same culture not for multiple cultures.

Please help me with this. Thanks in advance...!

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=csharp

Answer (score 1):

`Dispatch` feature provided for LUIS is language dependant as you mentioned (because LUIS is language dependant).

The best way to handle this case is to detect the language on your bot side (not on LUIS side) and then call the right LUIS model given the detected language.

This can be done by using `Detect language` from `Text Analytics API` in Microsoft Cognitive Services: https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c7

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Ok I can do an API call for detecting language. But how can I change the LUIS model? I am not doing API call for LUIS. Just configuring in Startup.cs. Please guide me on how to configure multiple LUIS Models??